# Problem with querying a many to one in django

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django. I was attempting to make a many to one query in my program.

I'm creating a clinic site, in which I want a list of patients for the given clinic to be shown.

I have the following `model.py` and `views.py`:

models.py

```
    class Klinik(models.Model):
        # code


    class Patient(models.Model):
        klinik = models.ForeignKey(Klinik, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

views.py

```
def kartotek(request, kl_id):

    klinikid = Klinik.objects.get(id=kl_id)

    patienter = Klinik.Patient_set.all()

    context = {'patients':patienter,}

    return render(request,'DentHelp/kartotek.html', context )
```

The error message is for the `_set.all()` attribute, but I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: `klinikid.Patient_set.all()`

Answer (score 0):

after getting the Klinik object, to fetch all patients linked to it you should use the object
like this: `klinikid.patient_set.all()`
patient_set is lowercase, and from the object, not the class Klinik

Also you can give to Patient field klinik a related name, this related_name will "override" the modelname_set
more on doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects